# Order of declaration of struct changing the output

Tags: c, procedural-programming

I am unable to understand the weird behavior of this program. I have 2 files, file1.c and file2.c

file.c is

```
#include <stdio.h>struct ll {
int key;
struct ll *next;
};
extern void func(struct ll*);

int main(void)
{
struct ll l = { 1, &l };
printf("%d %d\n",l.key,l.next->key);
func(&l);
return 0;
}
```

and file2.c is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

 struct ll 
 {
struct ll *next;    
int key;
 };


 void func(struct ll *l)
 {
   printf("%d \n",l->key);
   printf("%d \n",l->next->key);
 }
```

Now when I compile and run it, it shows segmentation fault. But where as in file2.c if I replace struct ll with :

```
struct ll 
{
 int key;   
 struct ll *next;       
};
```

Then it works fine. I mean just by interchanging the order of the declaration, it is impacting the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declaration of the struct should be the same both times, since struct is just a layout of data in memory, and you switch the variables.

in your case, the code in the function `func` will try to dereference the integer `1` set in the main function. (or maybe do other weird things, as int and pointer are not compatible)

In **file.c**:

```
struct ll: [ int (key)   | pointer (next) ]
struct ll l = { 1, &l }; // this causes:
l:         [ 1           | &l             ]
```

In **file2.c**:

```
struct ll: [ pointer (next) | int (key)   ]
// so the passed struct is treated in the same way:
l:         [ 1           | &l             ]
              next          key
```

Comment: See my edit, hope it  is clearer, if not, I'll try some more.

Comment: In between, from which argument in gcc did you generate that outline??

Comment: ...and this is why you should put the `struct` declaration into a `.h` file and `#include` it in the C files, so that it is definitely the same in both files.